# how can i find webdriver via webelement in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

In my code I have a reference to `WebElement` object but I have no reference to `WebDriver` object. Is there any way obtain a reference to `WebDriver` having just a `WebElement`

I need that since I need to invoke some `WebDriver`-specific functionality for a driver which has produced given `WebElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Normally there is no such a way. Most of `WebDriver` implementations does not put a public reference to itself to `WebElement`.

`RemoteWebElement`, which is produced by `RemoteWebDriver` which a lot of other drivers extend, has protected reference to `RemoteWebDriver`/`RemoteWebElement` so there are two ways here:

1. you can extend all those entities in your test project and expose that field public. This requires certain level of coding skills..
2. you can use reflection like shown in [this post](https://www.webelement.click/en/how_to_get_webdriver_object_from_webelement_object_selenium_java).